# What makes AES with Base64 generate different encryption result for the same plain text?

Tags: java, encryption, base64, aes

Here's a sample dummy code called test(), I run this 100K times and I get different encrypted messages for the same plain text (obviously, the decryption I get is the original plain text).

I guess the reason behind this is to avoid frequency; but how come there can be MANY encryption to ONE decryption? shouldn't it be a one to one?

```
public static void test()
{
    String plainMessage = "I'm gonna bid 100 USD on this project";
    String password = "A99922000001000004581F0F0CCD0000";

    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

    for (int x=0; x<100000; x++)
    { 
        String enc = AESEncryption.encryptMessage(plainMessage, password);
        System.out.println(enc);
        set.add(enc);

        String dec = AESEncryption.decryptMessage(enc, password);
        if (!dec.equals(plainMessage))
        {
            System.out.println("wrong decryption");  //never gets here 
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(">"+set.size()); //just to make sure they are all unique
}
```

the encryption

```
    public static String encryptMessage(final String plainMessage, final String symKeyHex) 
{
    final byte[] symKeyData = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(symKeyHex);
    final byte[] encodedMessage = plainMessage.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

    try {

        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        final int blockSize = cipher.getBlockSize();

        // create the key
        final SecretKeySpec symKey = new SecretKeySpec(symKeyData, "AES");

        // generate random IV using block size (possibly create a method for
        // this)
        final byte[] ivData = new byte[blockSize];
        final SecureRandom rnd = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        rnd.nextBytes(ivData);
        final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivData);

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, symKey, iv);

        final byte[] encryptedMessage = cipher.doFinal(encodedMessage);

        // concatenate IV and encrypted message
        final byte[] ivAndEncryptedMessage = new byte[ivData.length + encryptedMessage.length];
        System.arraycopy(ivData, 0, ivAndEncryptedMessage, 0, blockSize);
        System.arraycopy(encryptedMessage, 0, ivAndEncryptedMessage, blockSize, encryptedMessage.length);

        final String ivAndEncryptedMessageBase64 = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(ivAndEncryptedMessage);
        return ivAndEncryptedMessageBase64;


    }catch (InvalidKeyException e) 
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("key argument does not contain a valid AES key");

    }catch (GeneralSecurityException e) 
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected exception during encryption", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you're using a random IV

Comment: What do you think this does: `rnd.nextBytes(ivData);`?

Comment: I'll just add an IV is an Initialization Vector, and the purpose is to try and prevent known-text attacks against the cryptosystem.

Comment: Can I get this converted in Javascript ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add some clarity to the comments:

The *iv* or *initialization* *vector* is like a *second key* which is used to **encrypt** the data.

Since you use a random *iv* each time (this is good), you get different **encrypted text** each time.  This second *key* is actually included with the **encrypted text**, so you don't need to pass it along separately.

Having just the *iv* doesn't enable you to crack the **encryption** (which is why you can pass it along with the **encrypted text**), but by using it, you can send the same **plain text** with the same *password* multiple times (using different *ivs*) and get completely different **encrypted values**.

Comment: Do not use the term "key" to describe the IV. A second encryption/decryption parameter is ok, but not the second key.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin - why, specifically?

Comment: @jtahlborn just for testing purpose , what if i want to  generate similar encrypted string using the above code. How to do that