# How can I get the same encrypted text?

Tags: android, encryption, passwords, password-encryption

```
 String seedValue = "This Is MySecure";

 String normalText = "Password";

 normalTextEnc = AESHelper.encrypt(seedValue, normalText);

 System.out.println("encrypt"+normalTextEnc);
```

When I run this code again it gives me a another encrypted text.
How can i get the same encrypted text??

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24701068/what-makes-aes-with-base64-generate-different-encryption-result-for-the-same-pla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this. encrypt function will encrypt the message "This is the MESSAGE" with the password "key". Then we use the same password to decrypt the encrypted message in decrypt function. You can go through this link for more information. https://trivedihardik.wordpress.com/tag/android-aes-example/

```
        String encryptedData = AESHelper.encrypt("key", "This is the MESSAGE");
        System.out.println("Encoded String " + encryptedData);
        String decryptedData = AESHelper.decrypt("key", encryptedData);
        System.out.println("Decoded String " + decryptedData);
```